# C++: How can I allow user to retry if they accidentally enter more than one character in char variable?

Tags: c++, validation, char, user-input, cin

Question: In C++, ow do I make a program throw out an error when a user enters multiple characters for an input requesting a single character? I'd like to have the program re-prompt for a single character, but it just keeps going and entering the multiple characters on later lines.

This is a very simple program I wrote to test out character inputs and their properties to help me with another assignment. I wanted to see how it would react to multi-character inputs.

```
//Include statements
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//main statement

int main ()
{

    //name variables
    int numChar;
    char letterEntry;
    string finalWord = "";

    //begin entry

    cout << "This program will let you enter characters and combine them into a string." << endl;
    cout << "First tell us how many characters you want to enter." << endl;
    cin >> numChar;

    //convert characters to string and add to string variable
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter<numChar)
    {
        cout << "Enter a character!" << endl;
        cin >> letterEntry;

        finalWord = finalWord + string(1, letterEntry);
        counter++;
    }
    //Display final word
    cout << "Your word is " << finalWord << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

This is an output that demonstrates my issue.

```
This program will let you enter characters and combine them into a string.
First tell us how many characters you want to enter.
3
Enter a character!
DOGS
Enter a character!
Enter a character!
Your word is DOG
```

I want the program to not save anything if the user types in more than one character. I want it to print an error message that says "You entered more than one character, please retry," and lets them try again. Is there a way to do this with type char?

Thanks!

Comment: Read in a `std::string` and check if `length()` is greater one

Comment: See what happens when you enter less than the amount of characters requested. You get something you may not expect. Also note that you can read a character without prompting the user first...

Comment: If you only want `char` you can also use [`std::istream::peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) to check if there's another `char` excess input that's not a whitespace.

Comment: The Peek command did the trick; I've found it's easier to use type string for things like this in general, though. Thanks!